# Unable to run xcode-select --install

Tags: macos, xcode, high-sierra

I am on a MacBook Air running macOS High Sierra 10.13.2
When I run `xcode-select --install` to re-install Xcode developer tools, I am prompted to this

[image]

I choose `install` option which opens the agree terms prompt

[image]

agree terms and this appears

[image]

and nothing happens for 30 mins, so I tried to stop and it didn't work, I tried the quit option from the dock which didn't work either. I had to force quit `Install commandLine Developer Tools`. Can anyone help me how to reinstall CommandLine Developer Tools. Thank you

Comment: Can you tell me how to delete old xcode installation files? Mine never ends and each time it tries to update lots of GB disappears from my HD.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'd reboot the system and try again.

If that doesn't work, you can download it from [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com).

If you don't have an Apple Developer Account, you can create a free account, and then once signed in you can download the "Command Line Tools (macOS 10.13) for Xcode 9.1" from: [Downloads from Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)

[image: Downloads from Apple Developers]

Comment: I ran this and `ls -la /usr/bin | grep xcode` still returns nothing

Comment: @Ben Leggiero, What explicitly and specifically do you mean by "I ran this"? You ran what!? Also, on my system in Terminal,  `which xcode-select` returns `/usr/bin/xcode-select`. What version of OS X/macOS are you running?

Comment: I downloaded "Command Line Tools (macOS 10.13) for Xcode 10.1.dmg" from the page "More Downloads for Apple Developers". I opened that DMG and it mounted and a Finder window appeared presenting its contents. I opened the file "Command Line Tools (macOS High Sierra version 10.13).pkg" contained therein. The installer opened an **I ran that**, ensuring I had the machine's main drive selected and accepting the user agreement. Several minutes later it succeeded, yet when I open Terminal.app and run `ls -la /usr/bin | grep xcode` andor `which xcode-select` no lines are printed. I'm on macOS 10.13.6

Comment: @Ben Leggiero, The OP is the one that was having an issue with `xcode-select` and my answer primarily addressed how to install Command Line Tools for Xcode from Apple Developer site, so if you downloaded and install it... then why are you commenting on my answer? `xcode-select` is a part of macOS and is in the Core.pkg file of the macOS installer located in `/usr/bin` in the .pkg file. Why you do not have it on your system is not really the topic of the OP or this answer. I'd suggest posting your own question vs. a comment to an answer that really has nothing to do with its non-existence.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; I'll ask my own question

Comment: Command Line Tools (macOS 10.15) for Xcode - doesn't exist :(

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue on macOS High Sierra. Not being a Mac enthusiast, I went online to find some answers, but found none.

I eventually figured it out (at least in my case, a MacBook Air running High Sierra). The window that states *finding software* actually had another window hidden behind it, with a prompt asking if I wanted to continue on battery power?

Installation happened right away afterwards.

Comment: Same thing happened for me... what a nightmare.

Comment: Wow, and it wasn't even visible except on touchbar. Thank you so much!

Comment: glad i can help. it took me longer than I'm proud to admit to figure this out. Found it on accident moving it over to open a terminal

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was just waiting for the charger to get connected. That is confusing; at least it can prompt for it.

Click on stop; you will be able to resume the download.

Comment: OP in the last para indicated that Stop didn't work.