# When installing command line tools using Terminal, I am getting "Software currently unavailable from Software Update server" error

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, command-line, xcode, mojave

I have downloaded Xcode on my Mac running macOS Mojave and trying to install the command line tools using the following command:

`xcode-select --install`

But it is giving me the following error:

[image]

Why am I getting this error and how do I overcome this?

Comment: just solved for high sierra with https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309461/unable-to-run-xcode-select-install, downloaded from the developer site

Comment: Somethings messed up on Apple's end right now. Go to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ and search for *Command Line Tools*. You'll need a free Apple Developer account to download the installer.

Comment: Thank you iGian and joemaller for your responses. I have downloaded it from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/